# How to draw glucose using a Fischer projection?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, structural-formula

I asked how to draw glucose as a Fischer projection from its given chair conformation but all I got was an unsatisfactory ad hoc explanation involving rotation of my neck muscles to somehow see where the hydroxyl groups were. How does one actually draw a Fischer projection of a sugar molecule from its chair conformation? [image]

Comment: A Fischer projection of glucose would return about a gazillion hits on google. What exactly are you unsure about, if not found in these two simple references [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucose) and [2](http://www.chtf.stuba.sk/~szolcsanyi/education/files/Chemia%20heterocyklickych%20zlucenin/Prednaska%206/Odporucane%20studijne%20materialy/Drawing%20sugar%20structures.pdf)?

Comment: @long Reference 2 is an excellent description.

Comment: I find it a lot easier if you draw the ring as a Haworth projection. I'll post an answer later if no one else has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://biochemjm.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/fischer-and-haworth-projections-anomers/) is a web page that shows how to interpret the position from the structure.
The UP groups go to the left side of the backbone and the DOWN groups go to the right side.